# how to count the nodes in loop based on condition in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

Hi in below xml format i want to get the count of **S_fin** nodes where  **F_ba** date node is less than 18 monthns of current date. i have a function **to get date diffrence** here i just want to get the **count of nodes** which satisfy the conditon.

```
    <Root>
    <S_fin>
    <FS_ba>
      <F_ba>2013-10-29</F_ba>
      <F_BD desc="Fiscal">001</F_BD>
      <F_BF desc="Thousands">001</F_BF>
      <F_BG desc="Indian Rupee">9</F_BG>
    </FS_ba>
  </S_fin>
  <S_fin>
    <FS_ba>
      <F_ba>2012-10-29</F_ba>
      <F_BD desc="Fiscal">001</F_BD>
      <F_BF desc="Thousands">001</F_BF>
      <F_BG desc="Indian Rupee">9</F_BG>
    </FS_ba>
  </S_fin>
  <S_fin>
    <FS_ba>
        <F_ba>2011-10-29</F_ba>
      <F_BD desc="Fiscal">001</F_BD>
      <F_BF desc="Thousands">001</F_BF>
      <F_BG desc="Indian Rupee">9</F_BG>
    </FS_ba>
  </S_fin>
 <S_fin>
    <FS_ba>
      <F_ba>2013-10-29</F_ba>
      <F_BD desc="Fiscal">001</F_BD>
      <F_BF desc="Thousands">001</F_BF>
      <F_BG desc="Indian Rupee">9</F_BG>
    </FS_ba>
  </S_fin>
</Root>
```

Comment: XSLT 1.0 doesn't have any date functions itself, so are you using an extension function here? It would help if you showed any XSLT you currently have (especially an example of your date difference function). Showing your expected output would also help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In xslt it will look like that.

Add reference to your function in square brackets instead of checking for non-empty

```
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
          <cnt>
            <xsl:value-of select="count(S_fin[FS_ba/F_ba != ''])"/>
          </cnt>
     </xsl:template>
```